# Validate multiple image dimension with jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have input file with multiple attribute, now i want to validate the dimention. Here is my setup for jquery-validate

```
$("#AddForm").validate({
        rules: {
          'noteMedia[]': {
                extension: "jpg|jpeg|png",
                dimension:[1080,608],
            },
          
        },
        messages: {
          'noteMedia[]':{
                  extension: "Only image allowed" ,
                  dimension:"Image dimension Must 1080 * 608"
                }
            }
    });
```

here is my custom validation

```
  $.validator.addMethod('dimension', function(value, element, param) {
  if(element.files.length == 0){
      return true;
    }
    var no = 1;
    Array.from(element.files).forEach(imageData => {
      var fr = new FileReader;
        fr.onload = function() { 
          var img = new Image;
          img.onload = function() {
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;
            if(width > param[0] || height > param[1]){
                return false;
            }
          };
          img.src = fr.result; 
      };
       fr.readAsDataURL(imageData); 
       i = i+1
       console.log(i);
    });
    return true;
},'Please upload an image with 1080 x 608 pixels dimension');
```

My validation not working, the validation is not showing when i'm choose item with `1200*600`. How can i fix it ?

Comment: Maybe a typo? `addMethod('dimention'` should be "dimen**s**ion"

Comment: Where is the HTML?  How can we setup a demo if you don't show enough code?  Plus what @user7290573 just said; it's a critical error.